# How to configure buttons on Wacom Bamboo CTH-470 tablet to mouse clicks

Tags: 19.10, configuration, wacom, xinput, graphics-tablet

I have a Wacom Bamboo CTH-470 running on Ubuntu 19.10, everything works perfectly, from the pen to the pad, however the buttons on the tablet are not recognized, well, they get recognized but have no action other than in the settings menu. I went through a lot of searches, links and guides to finally get the buttons recognized "properly", meaning I went through xinput to xsetwacom to finally understanding how to map the buttons to its proper physical position. The only way I have to verify this is through "settings/devices/wacom Tablet" and when I click on the tab "Tablet" and click on "Map Buttons..." I can see the four buttons for which it gives me four options to select: "Application Defined", "Show on-screen Help", "Switch Monitor" and "Assign Keystroke".

When I press each of the buttons it shows the proper button selected and gives me this options, However I want to use the buttons as mouse clicks such as right click, left click, etc. I thought it would be a no-brainer but apparently it isn't so, I ran:

```
~$ xinput
```

`⎡ Virtual core pointer                     id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ ETPS/2 Elantech Touchpad                  id=16   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Kensington Expert Wireless TB Mouse       id=13   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Pen stylus          id=17   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Pen eraser          id=18   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Pad pad             id=19   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Finger touch        id=20   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎣ Virtual core keyboard                     id=3    [master keyboard (2)]
    ↳ Virtual core XTEST keyboard               id=5    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Power Button                              id=6    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Video Bus                                 id=7    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Sleep Button                              id=8    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ USB2.0 UVC 2M WebCam: USB2.0 UV           id=9    [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Asus Laptop extra buttons                 id=14   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ AT Translated Set 2 keyboard              id=15   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Kensington Expert Wireless TB Consumer Control    id=10   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Apple Inc. Apple Keyboard                 id=11   [slave  keyboard (3)]
    ↳ Apple Inc. Apple Keyboard                 id=12   [slave  keyboard (3)]`

From where I get the id:19 for the tablet, then:

```
~$ xinput get-button-map 19
```

`1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9`

This tells me that the buttons are assigned but as I click them, nothing happens. I then typed:

```
~$ xinput list 19
```

`Wacom Bamboo 16FG 4x5 Pad pad              id=19   [slave  pointer  (2)]
    Reporting 8 classes:
        Class originated from: 19. Type: XIButtonClass
        Buttons supported: 9
        Button labels: None None None None None None None None None
        Button state:
        Class originated from: 19. Type: XIKeyClass
        Keycodes supported: 248
        Class originated from: 19. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 0:
          Label: Abs X
          Range: 0.000000 - 0.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: absolute
          Current value: 0.000000
        Class originated from: 19. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 1:
          Label: Abs Y
          Range: 0.000000 - 0.000000
          Resolution: 0 units/m
          Mode: absolute
          Current value: 0.000000
        Class originated from: 19. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 2:
          Label: None
          Range: 0.000000 - 1.000000
          Resolution: 1 units/m
          Mode: absolute
          Current value: 0.000000
        Class originated from: 19. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 3:
          Label: None
          Range: 0.000000 - 1.000000
          Resolution: 1 units/m
          Mode: absolute
          Current value: 0.000000
        Class originated from: 19. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 4:
          Label: None
          Range: 0.000000 - 1.000000
          Resolution: 1 units/m
          Mode: absolute
          Current value: 0.000000
        Class originated from: 19. Type: XIValuatorClass
        Detail for Valuator 5:
          Label: None
          Range: 0.000000 - 1.000000
          Resolution: 1 units/m
          Mode: absolute
          Current value: 0.000000`

From this I assume the issue is that the "Buttons labels" are missing and that's the reason for them not to take any action.
My question is: Am I correct into assuming this?, if so, How can I modify the "Buttons labels"? and if I'm wrong, What can I do to assign left, right and middle clicks?

If anyone can throw a hand here will be much appreciated.
Thank you!